# Create a matrix with a changing number of columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to do an homemade version of peakfinder.m, by making it work with multiple arrays instead of just one at a time, for more time efficient performance. (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25500-peakfinder)

I have a 2D matrix where I need to find if the sign changes in the 2nd dimension.

```
dx0 = diff(x0,1,2); % Find derivative
dx0(dx0 == 0) = -eps; % This is so we find the first of repeated values
ind = find(dx0(:,1:end-1).*(dx0(:,2:end)) < 0)+1; % Find where the derivative changes sign
```

Now my problem is that it does find where the derivative changes sign, but it is one big vector. So if the signs changes twice in the same row (or doesn't in a row), I have no way to find out.

So if x0 is of size 1000x10, I'd like ind to be of size 1000xY, where Y is the number of times it changes sign in EACH row. I also need to know at which values of x0 there is a sign change. So each row will be in the style of :

```
2 4 7
4 8
2 5 6 8
```

etc.

Is this possible at all? Or should I change the code so it places a 0 if it doesn't change and a 1 if it does change, considering I'll be working with the values where it changes?

Comment: You have `1 3`. How can you have `1`, because there's nothing to the left of `1` and thus no sign change is possible there, or is there? Hope I am not making any absurd assumption. Or does the `1` mean that the second column of a row has a sign change from the first column of that row?

Comment: Arrr, I made a mistake writing gibberish :P You are indeed right, 1 cannot happen!

Comment: Right makes sense after the edit! :)

Comment: Just make sure to run a benchmark after you are finished. Simply operating on a matrix rather than separate vectors may not be sufficient to gain any performance.

Comment: Considering the actual size of my matrix is 264244x1000, I think it will be faster this way than using a "for" loop. But I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)** approach -

```
b1 = padarray(sign(dx0(:,1:end-1))~=sign(dx0(:,2:end)),[0 1],'pre')
out = cellfun(@find,mat2cell(b1,ones(1,size(b1,1)),size(b1,2)),'uni',0)
```

The above code assumes you have `padarray` which seems like a recent addition to MATLAB's Image Processing Toolbox. So, if you don't have it, you can concatenate `zeros` (with `false`) like this -

```
b1 = sign(dx0(:,1:end-1))~=sign(dx0(:,2:end))
b1 = [false(size(b1,1),1) b1]
out = cellfun(@find,mat2cell(b1,ones(1,size(b1,1)),size(b1,2)),'uni',0)
```

Alternative solution using `cellfun with nonzeros function` -

```
b1 = padarray(sign(dx0(:,1:end-1))~=sign(dx0(:,2:end)),[0 1],'pre')
out = cellfun(@nonzeros,mat2cell(bsxfun(@times,b1,1:size(b1,2)),ones(1,size(b1,1)),size(b1,2)),'uni',0)
```

`out` contains the locations of `sign` change across the rows, which can be displayed using `celldisp(out)`.

The `counts` of the `sign` changes can be calculated using -

```
counts = cellfun(@numel,out)
```

Comment: It is a truly witty way of getting around the problem. Thanks! There a few things not working right now, but I'll make it work!

Comment: maybe you will know why it gives me this error. I typed exactly what you wrote down, but it gives me an error saying : "Undefined function 'padarray' for input arguments of type 'double'." I am quite puzzled by this error!

Comment: Genius. This puzzles me since I have Matlab 2014a, so I thought I would have the padarray, but it seems I don't. Thank you again!

Comment: @Vissenbot Think you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox, which packages this `padarray` function. Sorry, I must have mentioned that, or let me add that info!